# jasmine test case file error while reading file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, jasmine

- I am trying to write a unit test case for my code.
- I am getting an error at this line myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
- I debugged the code if I see the value of file in readAsDataURL method.
- I see the below value
  **File {name: "Untitled-3.txt", lastModified: 1503251185773, lastModifiedDate: Sun Aug 20 2017 13:46:25 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 35693, …}**
- but not sure how to pass it in my unit test case method.
- so I am getting the below error..
  **TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.**
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code and test case below.

```or-tag-here
    testcase--->
    it('Read Financial player', (done) => {

                    console.log("Read------????");

            let callFirstTime : boolean = true;
            let url=

            spyOn(dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers.nbcuService,'getResponse').and.
                callFake(() => { 
                        if(callFirstTime){
                            callFirstTime = false; // Invoked by detectChanges() 
                            return Observable.of([{
                                "playerId": "100",
                                "playerName": "http://localhost:3000/assets/js/actualairings.json",
                                "playerType": "TITLE",
                                "playerData": "YWZjYXJlZ2Vyamh2dmFyZWdoYnZi",
                                "notes": "",
                                "notesId": "100",
                                "elfDocID": "100",
                                "url": "http://localhost:3000/upload",
                                "date": "06/27/2017",
                                "addedByName": "Kamal",
                                "userID": "206509786",
                                "operationType": "create"
                              }, {
                                "playerId": "101",
                                "playerName": "uploadTest4.txt",
                                "playerType": "TITLE",
                                "playerData": "Manish",
                                "notes": "",
                                "notesId": "101",
                                "elfDocID": "101",
                                "url": "http://localhost:3000/upload",
                                "date": "06/27/2017",
                                "addedByName": "Kamal",
                                "userID": "206509786",
                                "operationType": "create"
                              }]
                        );
                        }
                 });

                 //const args = ['p0', 'p1', 'p2'];
                //call_me.apply(this, args);

                 //var fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana'];
                 //var fruits1 = {"test": "1"};

                  //console.log("dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers---->" + 
                  //      JSON.stringify(dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers.blanket.apply(this, args)));

                 spyOn(dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers.gridkendo,'enableSaveplayer').and.returnValue(null);
                 //dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers.fileSelect = "text.txt";
                 //dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers.blanket(fruits[0]);
                //dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers.blanket(fruits1.test);
                dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers.blanket({
                    files: "Untitled-2.txt"
                });

                var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
                var file;
                myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                 //dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers.blanket( {0: File, length: 1});
                 //console.log("dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers._dataSource._data.length---->" + dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers._dataSource._data.length);
                 fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
               done();
               //expect(dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers._dataSource._data.length).toEqual(3);
            });

        });

 code----------->   
     blanket(inputValue: any): void {
        var that = this;
        var file: File = inputValue.files[0];

        var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
          this.encodeBase64 = myReader.result;
          that.fileSelect = $("#attachplayerBrowseBtn").val().replace(/^.*\\/, "");
          if (that.fileSelect == '') {
            that.dragDrop = that.clearBtn;
          } else {
            that.dragDrop = "";
            that.dragDrop = that.fileSelect;
          }
        }
        $('.addELFplayerForm').show();
        if (inputValue.files.length > 0) {
          var fileSize = 0;

          fileSize = inputValue.files[0].size / 1048576; //size in mb 

          if (fileSize > 5) {
            alert("The player size exceeds the max limit of 5 MB");

          }

          myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the browser `File` object actually represent a local file and contains that file's information. However when you stub that File object, it has only the information not the actual reference to the local file.

I suggest stubbing `readAsDataURL` and check if it receives the file object in your tests. And then returning a pre-defined DataUrl from your tests.

---

**Edit**

I would do something like this in your tests,

```
spyOn(window, 'FileReader').andReturn({
    readAsDataURL(){}
    onloadend(){}
});
```

you can replace `readAsDataURL()` and `onloadend()` with jasmine stubs and assert if they are called with proper arguments.

---

**Edit**

```
const fileReaderSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('FileReader', ['readAsDataURL', 'onloadend']);

spyOn(window, 'FileReader').andReturn(fileReaderSpy);

expect(fileReaderSpy.readAsDataURL). toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* your file object */);
expect(fileReaderSpy.onloadend). toHaveBeenCalledWith(/* your callback function */);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...its so confusing...can you update in my code :(

Comment: when I see in the browser console I see readAsDataURL as a method...can you tell me how to pass values into this methods :(

Comment: I would do something like this in your tests,


`
    spyOn(window, 'FileReader').andReturn({
        readAsDataURL(){}
        onloadend(){}
    });
`


you can replace `readAsDataURL()` and `onloadend()` with jasmine stubs and assert if they are called with proper arguments.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...I tested now but still same error...can you update in my code so confusing :(

Comment: you have to include it before you call `dashboardContractComponent.Financialplayers.blanket` in your tests

Comment: can you tell me how to do stubbing in readAsDataURL ...can you tell which values to print and see

Comment: Hey for the file object I should post the one which I posted in my question right??

Comment: And in my call back function should it be blanket method?? Confused :(

Comment: As a rule of thumb in unit tests, you would want to stub out any external dependencies. In case of your code, `window.FileReader` is an external dependency. And when `FileReader.readAsDataURL` is called it actually expects a reference to a local file being passed in.

`spyOn` is a method that jasmin provides to mock a functions and asset calls against them.

By using spyOn with `window.FileReader` you can mock the actual call to the `readAsDataURL` method and assert it's being called properly by doing something like `expect(fileReaderSpy.readAsDataURL). toHaveBeenCalledWith`.